# Nested tree DataFrame reshaping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data structured like in the picture below:

[image]

Input DataFrame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Material': 'FG', 'Component': 'COMP1'},
    {'Material': 'FG', 'Component': 'COMP2'},
    {'Material': 'COMP1', 'Component': 'RAW1'},
    {'Material': 'COMP1', 'Component': 'RAW2'},
    {'Material': 'COMP2', 'Component': 'RAW3'},
    {'Material': 'COMP3', 'Component': 'RAW4'}
])
```

[image]

I want to reshape the DF to have in the Material column the first parent element.
I was able to achieve this in the following way:

```
def reshape(r):
    parent = r['Material']
    while parent in df.Component.unique():
        parent = df[df.Component == parent].iloc[0]['Material']
    return parent
df['Material'] = df.apply(reshape, axis=1)
```

[image]

It works, but the performance is terrible. Does anybody knows more effective and elegant way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Material', target='Component',
                        create_using=nx.DiGraph)

def get_root(G, node):
    '''
    Find the root for a given node
    '''
    root = None

    # get the first predecessor of node
    # `root` is None if `node` has no predecessor
    for root in G.predecessors(node):
        break
    
    # return node if this is a root
    return (node if root is None 
                 else get_root(G, root)   # if not, recursive to find root
           )

df = pd.DataFrame([(get_root(G,node), node) for node in G], 
                   columns = ['Material', 'Component'])

# filter the root nodes 
df[df['Material']!= df['Component']]
```

---

**Update**: Instead of

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(get_root(G,node), node) for node in G], 
                   columns = ['Material', 'Component'])

# filter the root nodes 
df[df['Material']!= df['Component']]
```

just try:

```
df['Material'] = [get_root(G,node) for node in df['Component'] ]
```

Comment: Your solution is amazingly fast. However, I have an issue. The value order in the column "Component" is not preserved. And this is something I need to join other columns to the output DataFrame.

Comment: @Marek see updated answer if it's what you mean.

Comment: Perfect! It works incredibly well :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and use a series with index Component and values Material with `set_index`.

```
df['Material'] = df['Material'].replace(df.set_index('Component')['Material'])

print(df)
  Material Component
0       FG     COMP1
1       FG     COMP2
2       FG      RAW1
3       FG      RAW2
4       FG      RAW3
5    COMP3      RAW4
```

Comment: Shorter and twice much faster than my solution but still far too slow. I have over 80K rows in DataFrame. My solution takes 7 min, yours 3.5 min, but Quang's solution only 250 ms.